# Loop through JSON name/value pair string to populate form input field values for edit mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm trying loop through a json name/value pair string and populate generated input field values. Wanting this logic for edit mode. I feel I'm almost there but I'm only populating two fields. Oh, The input fields are in group of two (Title url and url itself)

// *** Edit mode *** - Populates input fields with current stored urls

```js
let wrapper = '#wrapper';
let urlJson = '{\"Hello World\": \"www.google.com\"\r\n}'

if (urlJson) {
  var result = $.parseJSON(urlJson);
  var urlTitle = $('[name="url_title[]"]');
  var url = $('[name="url[]"]');

  $.each(result, function(key, value) {
    console.log('key: ' + key + ' - value: ' + value);

    urlTitle.val(key);
    url.val(value);

    $(wrapper).append(
      '<div id="title_and_url_group"><br><hr class="title_and_url"><div class="col-md-9 title_and_url">' +
      '{!! Form::text("url_title", old("url_title"), ["class"=>"form-control", "name" => "url_title[]", "placeholder"=>"Title of URL"]) !!}' +
      '</div><br><div class="col-md-9 title_and_url">' +
      '{!! Form::text("url", old("url"), ["class"=>"form-control", "name" => "url[]", "placeholder"=>"Ex: http or https in url"]) !!}' +
      '<a href="#" title="Remove this field" class="remove_field text-danger float-right font-weight-bold p-1">X</a></div></div>'
    );
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" name="url_title[]" value="Bike"> URL Title<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="url[]" value="Car"> URL<br>
<div id="wrapper"></div>
```

Comment: could you please show us a valid Json to work with?

Answer (score 0):

You are using laravel's form facade in your javascript method, Laravel facade is executed at the server before the processed web page is passed to the client.

Since you're looping through js at client, form facade will be rendered as plain text, no php function will work, you'll need to write down the mark up instead of using Form Facade.

```
    Document.querySelector('#wrapper').innerHTML =
    result.forEach((res, index)=>{
      `<div id="title_and_url_group">
          <br>
          <hr class="title_and_url">
          <div class="col-md-9 title_and_url">
            <input type="text" name="url_title[${index}]" value="${res.url_title}" class="form-control">
          </div>
          <br>
          <div class="col-md-9 title_and_url">
            <input type="checkbox" name="url[${index}]" value="${res.url}" class="form-control">
            <a href="#" title="Remove this field" class="remove_field text-danger float-right font-weight-bold p-1">X</a>
          </div>`
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have this so far. I can't seem to get them into the values into the input fields. Here's the code. When I do a console.log it iterates correctly.

```
    // *** Edit mode *** - Populates url tile and url fields
    if (url) {
        var result = JSON.parse(url);
        var url_title = $('[name="url_title[]"]');
        var url = $('[name="url[]"]');

        $.each(result, function(key, value) {
         console.log('key: ' + key + ' - value: '  + value);

         url_title.val(key);
         url.val(value);

            $(wrapper).append(
                '<div id="title_and_url_group"><br><hr class="title_and_url"><div class="col-md-9 title_and_url">' + 
                '{!! Form::text("url_title", old("url_title"), ["class"=>"form-control", "name" => "url_title[]"]) !!}' +
                '</div><br><div class="col-md-9 title_and_url">' +
                '{!! Form::text("url", old("url"), ["class"=>"form-control", "name" => "url[]"]) !!}' +
                '<a href="#" title="Remove this field" class="remove_field text-danger float-right font-weight-bold p-1">X</a></div></div>'
            );
        });
    }
```

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention, wrapper is a variable:  var wrapper = $(".input_fields_wrap");